# Installing Apache2 from apt-src

Tags: debian, dependencies

I needed to make a few edits to Apache2 from source and now I can't figure out how to install it after it's been compiled. After I used `apt-src build apache2`, these .debs were created:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    1400 Jun 18 09:54 apache2_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6369022 Mar 23 15:30 apache2_2.2.16.orig.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1343978 Jun 18 09:54 apache2.2-bin_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  307208 Jun 18 09:54 apache2.2-common_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2668154 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-dbg_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2299360 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-doc_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_all.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2268 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-mpm-event_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2288 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-mpm-itk_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2304 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-mpm-prefork_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2240 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-mpm-worker_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  137330 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-prefork-dev_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   98264 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-suexec_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   99944 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-suexec-custom_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  138476 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-threaded-dev_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  164568 Jun 18 09:54 apache2-utils_2.2.16-6+squeeze1_i386.deb
```

However, I don't know how to install these w/o causing dependency issues. I tried just using `dpkg -i *.deb` but it returns:

```
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze1) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze1) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze1) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze1); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not configured yet.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.16-6+squeeze1); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is not configured yet.
```

How can I correctly install these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the .deb's, but it's trying to install the apache2 package first. The only way I can think of around this is to install the dependencies first, using something like this:

```
dpkg -i apache2-*.deb
dpkg -i apache2.2-*.deb
dpkg -i apache2_2*.deb
```

as the apache2-* and apache2.2-* packages seem to be depended on by the apache2_2* packages.